# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'pygame.Surface' objects

Tags: image, python-2.7, pygame, typeerror, string-concatenation

I am currently teaching myself game programming, and I've started nice and easy with pygame. I went through a tutorial that showed me how to build a simple game, and now that I am finished with it, I am in the process of trying to reorganize the code in a manner that makes sense to me, and also to edit it and add to it.

Part of what I tried to change is that instead of loading one '.png' file for a character, I load a list of them that will be iterated through in a 'move()' function I designed to make the characters look like they are moving. However I keep running into an error and I don't know why. Near the beginning of my code (all I've done is imported necessary modules and initialized pygame and some necessary variables) I tried to do the following code:

```
badguyimgs = ['badguy.png', 'badguy2.png', 'badguy3.png', 'badguy4.png']
for img in badguyimgs:
    badguyimgs.append(pygame.image.load("resources/images/" + img))
    badguyimgs.remove(img)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'pygame.Surface' objects
```

So far I have tried to initialize a new variable (resource = "resources/images/" + img) and place that at the beginning of the "for" loop and then insert that into the pygame.image.load(). I've also tried using os.path.join("resource/images/" + img). I've tried using the full path name ("c:\\Users\\ . . . \\resources\\images\\" +img). But any time I try to concatenate the pathname with the file name in the list, I get the above error code. I tried looking in the pygame documentation, but didn't see anything that helped in this situation. I've tried googling the error, but get nothing in reference to this. (a lot of issues with people tring to concatenate int types to strings though. . . ) I would appreciate any help anyone could give in pointing out why I am experiencing this, and what could fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're doing is appending the pygame.surface object (that you loaded from a png file) to the list while you're iterating through it. You are loading the images successfully. However after your function adds the first image and removes the string, your list looks like this:

```
badguyimgs = ['badguy2.png', 'badguy3.png', 'badguy4.png', pygame.image]
```

You are still iterating through the list, so your function starts trying to concatenate the string and the pygame.surface object. I would recommend creating an empty list, and add your loaded images to that list without adding or removing anything from the original. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that little bit of simple logic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to go with PlatypusVenom's explanation:

```
file_names = ['badguy.png', 'badguy2.png', 'badguy3.png', 'badguy4.png']
images = []
for file_name in file_names:
    images.append(pygame.image.load("resources/images/" + file_name))
```

Now the `pygame.Surface` objects are in `images`, and the variable names for the lists are less confusing.  Another option is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
images = [pygame.image.load("resources/images/" + file_name) for file_name in \
          ("badguy.png", "badguy2.png", "badguy3.png", "badguy4.png")]
```

This is similar to what you were going for in the code posted.  The list of strings will be removed from memory, leaving only `pygame.Surface` objects in the `images` list.